# How do i solve echo a tag URL

Tags: php

How do i solve the URL ?

i was using echo to call out the a tag. and it run well but the URL include something that are i no understand how do i solve it? and can anyone explain to me? why no URL will have thoes %20%20%

Here is the URL that i echo out

```
http://localhost/pme/main/directMessageRoom.php?directMessageRoomID=1></a>%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20method=
```

here is my code

```
<div class ="direct-message-btn-container ">
        <?php 

   include '../config.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $target = $_GET['user'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    $targetusername = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$target' ")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $username=  mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $dm_sql="SELECT * FROM direct_message_room WHERE user_1_id ='$id' AND user_2_id='$target' OR user_1_id='$target' AND user_2_id='$id'";
    $check_direct_message_room = mysqli_query($connection, $dm_sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $check=  mysqli_num_rows($check_direct_message_room);

    if($check == 0){

       $rowUserName=mysqli_fetch_array($username);
       $rowTargetUserName=mysqli_fetch_array($targetusername);
       $room_name=$rowUserName['username']. ' and ' . $rowTargetUserName['username'];

    $direct_message_room_name ="INSERT INTO direct_message_room(`direct_message_room_name`,`user_1_id`,`user_2_id`) VALUES ('$room_name','$id','$target')";

    $newDirectMessageRoom = mysqli_query($connection,$direct_message_room_name)or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $direct_message_room_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection); 

    echo '<a  href="directMessageRoom.php?directMessageRoomID='.$direct_message_room_id.'></a>';       
    }
    else{
        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($check_direct_message_room)){
             echo '<a  href="directMessageRoom.php?directMessageRoomID='.$row3['id'].'></a>';
        }                        
    } 
?>

    <form method="post" action="" role="form">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <input type = "submit" class="btn content-btn btn-direct-message" value="message" name="chat">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `include something are no used `? You aren't closing the href attribute in any of your links. You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: maybe i state it wrong but what i want to say is the URl back will have alot of %20%20%20% i no sure what is it

Comment: I think that is your browser trying to correct the broken `href`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the `href` attribute (double-quotes):

```
echo '<a href="directMessageRoom.php?directMessageRoomID='.$row3['id'].'"></a>';
                                                          right here ---^
```

Comment: But once i close it a tag i cant go to the URL... before i can echo is bug?

Comment: @Chew: What do you mean by "can't go to the URL"?  What is the actual HTML being emitted, what are you doing, and how is it failing?

Comment: I was doing is to check the the user 1 and user 2 have the chat room or no if no will insert 1 new room for both user cht and it will bring them to the directMessageRoom.php but once i close the a tag it wont perform any action it just remain at the page

Comment: @Chew: I'm afraid none of that makes any sense.  Can you be specific about the actual problem you're encountering?  HTML *by itself* doesn't "perform any action".  You'll need to explain specifically what you're actually doing and how it's failing.

Comment: Is ok i have fixed by myself but anyways thank you for your remind

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of lots of 'white-space' in your form field. Your submit button for example, you write this `<input type = "submit" ...>`. You are accidentally insert white space. It should be `<input type="submit" ...>`.